# C++ struct in union acces over union member

Tags: c++, struct, unions

i have a Struct which consists of an Union which consists of an uint32_t and another (anonym) struct. It looks like this:

```
struct sMesswertNummer {
union {
    uint32_t MesswertNummerFull;
    struct {
        uint16_t MesswertNummerPart:16;
        uint16_t AggregatNummer:16;
        uint8_t  AggregatSub:8;
        uint8_t  AggregatTyp:8;
    };
};
sMesswertNummer() { this->MesswertNummerFull=0; }
sMesswertNummer(uint16_t MesswertNummerPart,uint16_t AggregatNummer, uint8_t AggregatSub, uint8_t AggregatTyp) {
    this->MesswertNummerFull=0;
    this->MesswertNummerPart=MesswertNummerPart;
    this->AggregatNummer=AggregatNummer;
    this->AggregatSub=AggregatSub;
    this->AggregatTyp=AggregatTyp;
}
};
```

I initialze the struct with a Call of the Constructor like this

```
MesswertNummer(0x0001,0x0002,0x30,0x02);
```

After that my Variable has the right values, `Var.MesswertNummerPart` is 0x0001, `Var.AggregatNummer` is 0x0002 and so on.

But if i call Var.MesswertNummerFull i get 0x0001 (is MesswertNummerPart) instead of 0x023000020001 (0x02->AggregatTyp, 0x30->AggregatSubm 0x0002->AggregatNummer, 0x0001->MesswertNummerPart)

How can i get the whole Number with a call of Var.MesswertNummerFull?

Comment: Just solved the Problem by typing it again. MesswertNummerFull has to be a uint64_t (16+16+8+8 = 48)

Comment: You can also post your own answer.

Comment: Note that this use of unions is technically undefined. You're only supposed to use _one_ field of a union at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Lightness. I'll use masking and shifting instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved the Problem by typing it again. `MesswertNummerFull` has to be a `uint64_t` (16+16+8+8 = 48)